# .remove working in chrome and safari but not in FF & IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I found a jquery script to create a table and have one button to add rows to the bottom of the table. Then there are links on each row when clicked to delete that specific row. Everything works as expected in Chrome & Safari but not in FireFox or IE. Here is the Jquery.

```
    if ($("table#data tbody tr").size() == 1) {
    $('.deleteRowButton').hide();
}

$('.deleteRowButton').live('click',function() {
    var bid = $(this).attr('id');
    var nid = bid.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    var pid = $("#product" + nid).val();
    $("#productschanges").append("2:" + nid + ":" + pid + ","); 
    if ($("table#data tr").size() > 1) {
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();

    if ($("table#data tbody tr").size() == 1) {
        $('.deleteRowButton').hide();
    } else {
        $('.deleteRowButton').show();
    }
} else {
    $('.deleteRowButton').hide();
}
});

$(".addRowButton").click(function() {
    $("table#data tbody tr:last").clone(true).find("select").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) {
                return this.id.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + i;
            },
            'name': function(_, name) {
                return this.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + i;
            },
            'value': function(_, value) {
                return '';
            }
        });
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);

    }).end().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) {
                return this.id.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + i;
            },
            'name': function(_, name) {
                return this.name.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + i;
            },
            'value': function(_, value) {
                return '';
            }
        });

    }).end().find("button").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) {
                return this.id.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') + i;
            },
        });

    }).end().appendTo("table#data tbody");
    i++;

    $('.deleteRowButton').show();
});
```

The append within .deleteRowButton works in all browsers but the line is not removed as expected. Any help on why this isn't working in the two browsers?

Thanks
2Pher

Comment: Did you see any javascipt errors in IE or FF console?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I've seen no errors. I tried making a fiddle but I couldn't even get the add row to work in fiddle. here is a link to a test page I created and if you use chrome or safari both Add Ingredient & Remove Ingredient work. However in Firefox (and I believe IE, I don't have it to test), the Remove Ingredient button does not work. http://skafreaksonline.com/test.php?func=edit&editid=5

Comment: I am still curious as to why the .remove wasn't working but I found a solution which is to use .hide instead and it just hides the row. So instead of having this line
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
I have this
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();

Comment: OK, Sorry all but cancel that last thought on having it working. This would work but if I hide the last row then try to add a new one it doesn't show up cause it is just cloning the previous (hidden) row. If I could get it to show up then it would work but cant figure that out.

Comment: So it seems its not working because of the select field within the row. I removed that and it worked. Any way to get it to work with the select in it?

Answer (score 0):

I view your source html. I see many html tags is not correct position.  before tag style has close tag not any open tag.
You should fix this error. has open tag and close tag valid.

Comment: I know not every tag is perfect, I'm just an amateur coder, but I'm not really sure what you meant by that.

Comment: hey. You should do it. When open tag does not match close tag, it may occur uncontrollable errors.

Comment: I understand I should fix a tag but I don't understand what tag you are talking about.